# jquery datepicker trigger unexpected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I used a checkbox to toggle a date entry box with datepicker. But when I click the picker, it triggered the checkbox change event (unexpected). What did I make wrong? Here is the code snippet.

TIA

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery show or hide based on other</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
 <script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script>
 $(function() {
  $("#pickDate").change(function() 
  {   
    alert("call pick date change event");
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
       $("#dateDiv").hide();
    }
else {
      $("#dateDiv").show();
   } 
 });

 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

 $( "#endDate" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7, dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',  maxDate: "+1m+3w", minDate: -10});

 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="selection1">
 <label for="toggle date">Show selection criteria<label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="pickDate" name="pick_Date">
 <br><br>
 <div id="dateDiv" style="display:none">
 <label for="start_date">Start Date:</label>
 <input type="textbox" name="start_date" id="datepicker" size="30">
 </div>
 </div>

 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="endDate" size="30" /> </P>`enter code here`

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g78SP/1/

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gJab8/

Comment: which is the browser used

Comment: chrome was used. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like FireFox has a problem.

You have not closed a label properly(`<label for="toggle date">Show selection criteria<label>` 2 open tags, no closing tag)

```
<label for="pickDate">Show selection criteria
    <input type="checkbox" id="pickDate" name="pick_Date"/>
</label>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g78SP/)

Comment: Yes, add the missing closing label, it works. I am not clear why the event was called just due to the missing closing tag.